# perl nested hash multiple sort

Tags: perl, hashtable

I have structure which looks like this (hash of hashes):

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Lee2000a' => {
                'abstract' => 'Abstract goes here',
                'author' => 'Lee, Wenke and Stolfo, Salvatore J'
                'title' => 'Data mining approaches for intrusion detection'
                'year' => '2000'
              },
          'Forrest1996' => {
                'abstract' => 'Abstract goes here',
                'author' => 'Forrest, Stephanie and Hofmeyr, Steven A. and Anil, Somayaji'
                'title' => 'Computer immunology'
                'year' => '1996'
                }
        };
```

I would like to sort this structure according three conditions (in this order):

1st - according year value (1996,2000)
2nd - according "outer" (Lee2000a, Forrest1996) structure keys
3rd - according to "inner" structure keys (abstract, author, title, year) in alpahabetical order.

So far I have two codes which I need to combine somehow:

I. code meets 2nd and 3rd criterium

```
for $i (sort keys(%bibliography)){
   print "$i => ", "\n";
   for $j (sort keys ($bibliography{"$i"})){
   print "\t $j -> ", $bibliography{"$i"}{"$j"},"\n";
   }
}
```

II. code meets 1st condition

```
for $i (sort { ($bibliography{$a}->{year} || 0) <=> ($bibliography{$b}->{year} || 0) } keys %bibliography){
  print "$i => ", "\n";
  for $j (sort keys ($bibliography{"$i"})){
    print "\t $j -> ", $bibliography{"$i"}{"$j"},"\n";
  }
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but how to do this, as a newbie I am not very familiar with stackoverflow concept? Also If you please could explain how some user can paste codes here, I only see "Add Comment" button which when is used to add code then makes this code horribe foramting. (also there is limitation of I guess 600 characters). Thank you very much.

Comment: you might find the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) helpful and the extra help linked from there. Specifically, though, I see you have managed to accept answers, which is great. For pasting code, it depends on why you need to do this. But generally, you can only paste in formatted code into a question or answer - you can't do this in comments. To format it properly, click the `{ }` button above the text box to indent everything highlighted by at least 4 spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To sort by some secondary condition, you can use a logical OR:

```
my @sorted = sort {
                 $a{c1} <=> $b{c1} || 
                 $a{c2} <=> $b{c2}
             } @unsorted
```

This example will sort the hashes in `@unsorted` by the key `c1` and then, if this comparison is equal, by the key `c2`.

For your purposes you can combine the two sorting comparisons for the outer loops this way so that your sort block will read:

```
(($bibliography{$a}->{year} || 0) <=> ($bibliography{$b}->{year} || 0)) ||
($a cmp $b)
```

Answer (score 2):

**[UPDATE]** added a simpler version that simply returns the keys on the input hash bashed on the sort conditions.

### 1st approach: Return a sorted list

We want to sort a hash, and the sort conditions include both the keys and stuff nested in the values. To do a 1 pass sort, where each `$a` and `$b` can be compared, it might be handy to convert the transform the hash a a list that makes available each key and value in the hash.

A bit wasteful, but works:

```perl
my @sorted = 
 sort {
    $a->{val}->{year} <=> $b->{val}->{year} ||             # 1st condition
    $a->{key} <=> $b->{key} ||                             # 2nd condition
    $a->{val}->{abstract} <=> $b->{val}->{abstract} ||     # 3rd condition
    $a->{val}->{author} <=> $b->{val}->{author} ||         # (not really sure
    $a->{val}->{title} <=> $b->{val}->{title} ||           # how you wanted this
    $a->{val}->{year} <=> $b->{val}->{year}
  } map { { val => $biblio{$_}, key => $_  }  } keys %biblio;
```

We're sorting a Hash; we need a list as a return value. In which case, where would `Forrest1996` and `Lee2000a` fit? I thought it might make sense to convert the hash to a *list of hashes* each of which have 2 properties - a `key` and a `val`.

So the return value of the sort would be a list of hashes like this:

```
@sorted = (
      {
        'val' => {
                   'title' => 'Computer immunology',
                   'author' => 'Forrest, Stephanie and Hofmeyr, Steven A. and Anil, Somayaji',
                   'abstract' => 'Abstract goes here',
                   'year' => 1996
                 },
        'key' => 'Forrest1996'
      },
      {
        'val' => {
                   'title' => 'Data mining approaches for intrusion detection',
                   'author' => 'Lee, Wenke and Stolfo, Salvatore J',
                   'abstract' => 'Abstract goes here',
                   'year' => 2000
                 },
        'key' => 'Lee2000a'
      }
  )
```

### 2nd Approach: Return just a list of the keys based on the sort conditions

I guess, after reading the comments and reconsidering, it's good enough and lighter to just return the keys of the input hash:

```
my @sorted = 
  sort {
    $biblio{$a}->{year} <=> $biblio{$b}->{year} ||         # 1st condition
    $a <=> $b ||                                           # 2nd condition
    $biblio{$a}->{abstract} <=> $biblio{$b}->{abstract} || # 3rd condition
    $biblio{$a}->{author} <=> $biblio{$b}->{author}        # ...and so on
   } keys %biblio;
```

... which just returns

```
 @sorted = (
      'Forrest1996',
      'Lee2000a'
 );
```

Comment: It probably will work, but why is it easier to write that than use two `for` loops?

Comment: What is your reason for remapping key/value pairs? The resulting sorted list will be a rather confusing mess.

Comment: Hashes have no order, right? So I guess one needs to return a list/array? which means, the original 'key' of the hash must be preserved somewhere, and I though calling it `key` made sense?

Comment: @TLP good point - but then, what would be a good return format? a list of just the values in the hash?

Comment: Well, assuming the original hash remains, a list of keys would be suitable. No need to complicate things.

Comment: @Faiz This is all perfectly useful if there is a need to persist with the data structure's order. But generally hashes are sorted just before they are written out in some fashion.

Comment: @Mattrition You know - you're right. Just keys would have been good enough. Guess it could be re-written that way...